# Is it possible to get Intent from running Activity from another application?

Tags: android, android-intent

I will prevent some application to be deleted from the phone.

Now, I can get current top activity name using `ActityManager` and check if it is `com.android.packageinstaller.UninstallerActivity`, than do additional logic for checking which package will be deleted. but I can't get `UninstallerActivity` object, and more - I can't get `Intent` passed to `com.android.packageinstaller.UninstallerActivity` (which will provide package name for me).

Seems like this isn't possible with standart `Android API` way. maybe it's possible using hidden `API` and reflection.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** I'm writing `Launcher` application, which will be distributed manually in hotels. I will have functionality which prevents from deleting my `Launcher` application from the phone, because mobile phones will be given in rent, and Launcher replacement isn't possible.

*Note:* The phone will be rooted!

Comment: Why do you think that what you are proposing is ethical?

Comment: added additional information about application. see "Edit", please

Comment: Why not install your launcher on the system partition?

Comment: as I know, system apps can't be deleted, but they can be disabled from settings.

Comment: or not, can't be disabled. seems like, moving application to system apps will solve my problem. Thank you